# GPU passthrough security

Tags: linux, virtualization, gpu, kvm

How secure is the host operating system from the guest virtual machine's OS when using GPU passthrough (using the methods described [here](https://vfio.blogspot.com/2015/05/vfio-gpu-how-to-series-part-3-host.html))?

If the guest is compromised, can it permanently infect the GPU and its firmware? If it's possible, what could this compromised GPU do?

- Even though VT-d/IOMMU is designed to securely contain devices to the
  virtual machine, could the guest use the GPU to compromise the host
  (OS or any other devices)?
- <s>If the GPU is suspected compromised, what should be the ideal course 
  of action? If the computer's host OS is reinstalled, would the GPU be
  able to attack and infect it?</s>
  (Moved to [separate question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/162176/151155))

I'm looking for a general answer, but if it's relevant, assume Linux
host with KVM and Windows guest.

Comment: There is a proof-of-concept [GPU rootkit jellyfish](https://github.com/x0r1/jellyfish) on github. It survives reboot, but not a shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

- > If the guest is compromised, can it permanently infect the GPU and its
  >   firmware?

According to OpenStack [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/security-guide/compute/hardening-the-virtualization-layers.html#physical-hardware-pci-passthrough), **yes**.

> Many hypervisors offer a functionality known as PCI passthrough. This
>   allows an instance to have direct access to a piece of hardware on the
>   node. For example, this could be used to allow instances to access
>   video cards or GPUs offering the compute unified device architecture
>   (CUDA) for high performance computation.
>
> This feature carries two types of security risks: direct memory access
>   and **hardware infection**.

Direct memory access is only relevant to device passthrough not using IOMMU.

- > Even though VT-d/IOMMU is designed to securely contain devices to the
  >   virtual machine, could the guest use the GPU to compromise the host
  >   (OS or any other devices)?

Possibly, if the device is used by the host.

> A hardware infection occurs when an instance makes a malicious
>   modification to the firmware or some other part of a device. **As this
>   device is used by other instances or the host OS, the malicious code
>   can spread into those systems.** The end result is that one instance can
>   run code outside of its security domain. This is a significant breach
>   as it is harder to reset the state of physical hardware than virtual
>   hardware, and can lead to additional exposure such as access to the
>   management network.

Comment: Is the device "used" by the host after VM shutdown? Or at any other time?

Comment: At the very least the device is "used" by the BIOS when the host machine is next rebooted and it tries to figure out what devices are in the system.

Comment: I think hardware infection requires access to PCI configuration space (to write option ROMs). I don't think CUDA is sufficient to actually "infect" a GPU with persistent code.